# Prestashop - event after product update

Tags: php, product, prestashop

I have a question - is there any option to do something like triggers in prestashop ? I want to do some after or before product update action ? Is there some options ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a bunch of hooks for these things. For the save action of products you'll need the `actionProductSave` or `actionProductUpdate` hooks. You will be able to use this in a module to trigger whatever you want.